# NEST Searching all fields

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I'm trying to construct a NEST search that queries all fields both integer and string on every nested level to find a match.

Additionally, being able to pass in a certain masterProductID from which only products under the masterProduct will be searched by would be fantastic, but this is not needed.

I can't figure out how to compound the queries for three or four levels and whenever I pass in "1" for example, Elastic never returns anywhere it found the integer 1. Both these need to be implemented and Elastic's documentation on nesting has no examples of much use.

Below is a very condensed outline of the sort of hierarchy I'm dealing with. (It's even worse than this, this is the index that was handed to me to search with).

Is there any easy way to do this I'm missing?

Thanks in advance.

```
 "masterProductId":2
 "manufacturerId" : 1
 "productAttributes": [
      {
        "masterProductId": 2,
        "attributeTypeName": "Storage",
        "attributeTypeId": 2,
        "attributeName": "16GB",
        "attributeId": 4,
        "productId": 1124,
        "attributeSortOrder": 2,
        "attributeTypeSortOrder": 1,
        "attributeNameUrl": "16gb"
      },
      {
        "masterProductId": 2,
        "attributeTypeName": "Condition",
        "attributeTypeId": 5,
        "attributeName": "Refurbished Good",
        "value": "Excellent condition with very minor, isolated wear and tear",
        "attributeId": 30,
        "productId": 1124,
        "attributeSortOrder": 3,
        "attributeTypeSortOrder": 4,
        "attributeNameUrl": "refurbished-good"
      }
      "products": [
            {
              "masterProductId": 2,
              "productId": 37,
              "basePrice": 110,
              "websitePriceIncTax": 110,
              "productImages": [
                {
                  "productImageId": 0,
                  "masterProductId": 2,
                  "productId": 37,
                  "name": "Apple iPhone 4s White",
                  "productImageTypeId": 2,
                  "productImageTypeName": "Front",
                  "imageExtension": "jpg",
                  "fileName": "front-appleiphone4swhite.jpg",
                  "fileNameThumb": "front-appleiphone4swhite-thumb.jpg",
                  "isDefault": true
                }
```

Comment: Would you be able to include the mapping for the index in question? The example provided looks a bit strange e.g. is `"products"` property within `"productAttributes"` array, or should there be a closing array bracket before `"products"`?

Comment: @RussCam the man working on this system before me decided to use automapping from a huge object nesting smaller objects inside it (I know, right..) A full example mapping would be over 16,800 lines in Kibana, which wouldn't exactly be easy to look through. I guess there's no "search everywhere" function?

Comment: There's an `_all` field in versions prior to 6.x that can be used to search across all document fields but is deprecated in 6.x. You can set your own up with `copy_to` in 6.x. `_all` does not include fields from `nested` datatypes if I recall correctly though. See https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/copy-to.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution I could find ultimately was to manually reference every individual index to search on using various compounds of search types. Simplifying the object to the minimum number of fields was necessary.